# The file system type of my home partition is 'swsuspend'. Is this recoverable?

Tags: arch-linux, filesystems, partition

Here's how this happened:

I've got separate root, home, boot and swap partitions for my Arch Linux installation.  Today I booted from a USB stick and mounted my root, boot and home partitions to `/mnt`, `/mnt/boot` and `/mnt/home` respectively.  I then `arch-chroot`ed into `/mnt`.

At this point, I did something I probably shouldn't have done, and ran `startx`.  An X-windows interface popped up, but was unresponsive.  I eventually pressed the shutdown button on my computer and Arch shut down.  Now when I boot up, my home partition fails to mount, giving the error

```
unknown filesystem type "swsuspend"
```

Will I need to recreate the partition from scratch (losing all my data on `/home` or is this recoverable somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for other superblock on the partiton:
dumpe2fs /dev/sdxn | grep -i superblock
You should be able to find some and recover from there.

A full set of instructions can be found here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/recover-bad-superblock-from-corrupted-partition/